# Running batch file in notification area

Tags: windows, taskbar, batch-file, notification-area

Is there any simple code that will make my batch file process, when run, to go to the notification area rather than the taskbar?

Comment: Raymond Chen will curse you for [mis-using the notification area for something that isn't a notification](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/11/01/922449.aspx).

Comment: Raymond Chen needs to pay better attention to what happens in the real world

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rbtray, traydevil and dm2 are all utilities for running processes in the tray.

I don't think this is something you could just code in a batch file natively.

Comment: Raymond Chen will curse you for [incorrectly calling it a tray](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/09/10/54831.aspx).