# Send taskbar icon to statusbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, shortcuts, statusbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running batch file in notification area](https://superuser.com/questions/338898/running-batch-file-in-notification-area)

I've set up a batch file which runs an application via the command line. For the application to keep running I need to keep that instance of the command line open. But I'd also like to hide the icon from the task bar and place it in the statusbar instead. Is there some way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is also freewares that does this, for example: [4t-Tray Minimizer](http://download.cnet.com/4t-Tray-Minimizer-Free/3000-2072_4-10079431.html)
With AutoHotKey you can also create programs that does this like this one: [link](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic4418.html), the advantage is that you can easily customize it since the source code is given.